# Inlined ARM64 system call giving the wrong return value

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, arm64

This is my code.

```cpp
long doSystemCall(const char *path) {
    register long x0 asm("x0") = 0;
    register long x1 asm("x1") = (long) path;
    register long x2 asm("x2") = 0;
    register long x3 asm("x3") = 0;
    register long x8 asm("x8") = __NR_faccessat;

    __asm__ volatile("svc #0"
    :"=r"(x0)
    :"0"(x0), "r"(x1), "r"(x2), "r"(x3), "r"(x8)
    :"memory"
    );

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SYSCALL", "Result: %li", x0);

    return x0;
}
```

The return values it gives are `0`, `-2` or `-13`, however `faccessat` should only return `0` or `-1`. How can I fix this?

The decompiled pseudocode of my code looks like this.

```cpp
signed __int64 __fastcall sub_E558(const char *a1)
{
  signed __int64 v1; // ST30_8
  v1 = linux_eabi_syscall(__NR_faccessat, 0, a1, 0, 0);
  __android_log_print(4LL, "SYSCALL", "Result: %li", v1);
  return v1;
}
```

And these are the instructions of the function.

```
SUB             SP, SP, #0x50
STP             X29, X30, [SP,#0x40+var_s0]
ADD             X29, SP, #0x40
STUR            X0, [X29,#var_8]
MOV             X0, XZR
STUR            X0, [X29,#var_10]
LDUR            X8, [X29,#var_8]
STUR            X8, [X29,#var_18]
STR             X0, [SP,#0x40+var_20]
STR             X0, [SP,#0x40+var_28]
MOV             W9, #0x30
MOV             W8, W9
STR             X8, [SP,#0x40+var_30]
LDUR            X0, [X29,#var_10]
LDUR            X1, [X29,#var_18]
LDR             X2, [SP,#0x40+var_20]
LDR             X3, [SP,#0x40+var_28]
LDR             X8, [SP,#0x40+var_30]
SVC             0
STUR            X0, [X29,#var_10]
LDUR            X3, [X29,#var_10]
ADRP            X1, #aSyscall@PAGE ; "SYSCALL"
ADD             X1, X1, #aSyscall@PAGEOFF ; "SYSCALL"
ADRP            X2, #aResultLi@PAGE ; "Result: %li"
ADD             X2, X2, #aResultLi@PAGEOFF ; "Result: %li"
MOV             W0, #4
BL              .__android_log_print
LDUR            X8, [X29,#var_10]
STR             W0, [SP,#0x40+var_34]
MOV             X0, X8
LDP             X29, X30, [SP,#0x40+var_s0]
ADD             SP, SP, #0x50
RET
```

Comment: What OS are you using?  Why do you think it should only return 0 or -1 (EPERM)?  According to the Linux man page, it might return EACCESS(-13), ELOOP, ENAMETOOLONG, ENOENT(-2), ENOTDIR, EROFS, EFAULT, EINVAL, EIO, ENOMEM, ETXTBUSY, or EBADF.  EPERM is not even mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing the libc wrapper API with the direct syscall ABI -- only the libc wrapper returns errors in errno.  The direct system call will return a small neagtive value (with the error code), at least on Linux.  The libc wrapper will test the return value, and if it is the range -4096..-1, will negate it and store it in errno (and then return -1).  Other UNIX variants (BSD) return the error indication in a flag (usually carry flag) with the error value in the return register.